# Read uploaded file with csv.reader

Tags: django

Task: read uploaded file to check structure. My test upload file has 5 lines with header and about 20-30 columns. Encoding is ISO-8859-1

Sounds simple but it drives me slowly into insanity.
The only working solution at the moment is detour about Models:

```
file = request.FILES.getlist('job_file', None)[0]
newdoc = models.Jobs(job_file=file)
newdoc.save()
with codecs.open(newdoc.job_file.name, "r", encoding='iso-8859-1') as fp:
    file_content = list(csv.reader(fp, delimiter=';', quotechar='"'))
```

Dirty, crazy and far from acceptable

Non working solutions:
1:

```
file_content = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=';', quotechar='"'))
print(file_content)
>>>_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

2:

```
file_content = list(csv.reader(file.open('r'), delimiter=';', quotechar='"'))
print(file_content)
>>> TypeError: argument 1 must be an iterator
```

3:

```
file_content = list(csv.reader(file.read(), delimiter=';', quotechar='"'))
print(file_content)
>>>_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not int (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

Some hints:

```
print(file.read())
>>>b';"";""\r\n' <-- WRONG see file content at the top
print(file.readlines())
>>>[]
```

Please save me!

Comment: give a shot to: `data = csv.reader(request.FILES.getlist('job_file', None)[0], delimiter=';', quotechar='"')` and if it does not work try with: `csv.reader(codecs.EncodedFile(request.FILES.getlist('job_file', None)[0], "iso-8859-1"), delimiter=';', quotechar='"')`

Comment: `_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`  for both :(

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to open file, you can convert your uploaded file to `TextIOWrapper`. Here is cleaner example

```
from io import StringIO

file = request.FILES.getlist('job_file', None)[0]
newdoc = models.Jobs.objects.create(job_file=file)
fp = StringIO(file.read(), encoding='iso-8859-1')
file_content = list(csv.reader(fp, delimiter=';', quotechar='"'))
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'readable'`

Comment: @StefanWeiss could you provide full traceback, I have similar code in my project, and everything works ok.

Comment: >>everything works ok - thats my current problem. i used many internet solutions, that worked for other people, but it doesn't work for me. it has to be small difference between my example and others. but i can't find it. full traceback would be to big:`File "F:\python\my_project\main\views.py", line 1497, in url_check_test_file
    fp = TextIOWrapper(file, encoding='iso-8859-1')
AttributeError: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'readable'`

Comment: currently working solution:`file.open('r')
                        f = StringIO(file.read().decode('iso-8859-1'))

                        file_content = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=';', quotechar='"'))`

Comment: @StefanWeiss I see that you are doing this on Windows, what version of django and python you are using?

Comment: Python 3.4 and django 1.10

Answer (score 1):

```
uploaded = request.FILES.getlist('job_file', None)[0]
decoded_file = uploaded_file.read().decode('ISO-8859-1').splitlines()
file_content = list(csv.reader(decoded_file, delimiter=';', quotechar='"'))
```